# Must only use a test bank account number when making transfers or debits in test mode; request-id: req_8bwGXgBiv

Tags: stripe-connect

I am facing a problem in giving our external bank details to create or update the account using the test account number and routing numbers, it says:

> Must only use a test bank account number when making transfers or debits in test mode; request-id: req_8bwGXgBiv.

Without external bank account update and creations are working good. I need to put my external bank details I am facing the issue.
I am stacked in here to update my account.

I am using `account_number = 000123456789` and `routing_number = 110000000` this account and routing numbers are given by `stripe api`

> Map externalAccountParams = new HashMap(); externalAccountParams.put("routing_number", stripeAccount.getBankRoute());
>   externalAccountParams.put("account_number", stripeAccount.getBankAccount());
>               accountParams.put("external_account", externalAccountParams);

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am getting the same issue.

Comment: similar 
"You cannot use a live bank account number when making transfers or debits in test mode"

Answer (score 20):

The test bank account numbers for Stripe Connect can be found [here in their documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing); to get the numbers for a specific country there's a little dropdown for you to select the relevant one. For convenience, the standard test bank account numbers below:

- US - 000123456789
- UK - 00012345
- JP - 00012345

Comment: @NeerajPrajapati it's also in the documentation - Ireland is in the EU so you can use the appropriate IBAN (eg IE89370400440532013000 - Payout succeeds)

Answer (score 7):

I suspect your HashMap is handling the account number as an integer and truncating the leading zeroes.  The test account set up by Stripe must contain all 12 digits, including the 3 leading zeroes.

Stripe returned the same error message for me when I used an invalid account number (ex: 123456).  The request went through correctly only after using the test account number 000123456789.

Answer (score 2):

Stripe connect credentials for United Kingdom account:

```
SSN: 000000000
Date: Any previous date
Account Number: 00012345
Routing: 110000000
```

It works for me. Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone testing Au Becs Debit for Australian accounts, test bank accounts are listed for Connect here (although you may not be working on Stripe Connect). Hope it saves you a bit of time.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing

Answer (score 0):

Bank number for JP

ACCOUNT     ROUTING
00012345    1100000

Answer (score 0):

More test bank accounts can be found here
https://stripe.com/docs/testing

For example:

Routing number **110000000**

Account Number **000222222227** //The payment fails due to insufficient funds.

Answer (score 0):

For UK working for me

Routing number 108800
Account Number 00012345

[image: stripe test account]